# Failing to #include <android/log.h> (or call it) in ndk-build on windows

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am trying to write to the android logcat from within a ndk .so project written in c.  It is configured as a hybrid project that can compile either as a .dll for windows or .so for android;  so far the .dll runs fine but the .so crashes out with a NullPointerException before anything happens.

So, short of debugging the .so (something else I have no idea how to do) I'm trying to start by writing to the Android LogCat.  I've written #include <android/log.h> in the .c , and, failing to understand any other way of doing it, copied the whole of /android and all its header files from the ndk over to the project directory.

From the project /jni directory with the Android.mk and Application.mk I run E:\Downloads\android-ndk-r25c-windows\android-ndk-r25c\ndk-build (which has been working before I added the line of log call) and the resulting error is

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: __android_log_write
>>> referenced by convolution.c:1527 (../convolution.c:1527)
```

Now, I'm not sure that this is actually a failure to link to the log.h file, because, if I replace #include <android/log.h> with some rubbish like #include <android/dkl.h> I get

```
convolution.c:34:10: fatal error: 'android/dkl.h' file not found
#include <android/dkl.h>
```

Finally, I wonder if I'm making the call correctly, the actual attempted line is

```
__android_log_write(3, "JoeDynamics", "bogoStart");
```

Quite possibly this is wrong but I'd have thought that if that were the case, it'd complain that the particular call input pattern is undefined, rather than that the whole function name doesn't exist?

Regarding suggestions to study C from scratch from previous questions, unfortunately this is far from my main job and I'm only trying to write / modify a little plugin to a huge existing framework, so I feel that working backwards, however confusing it may be, will still save me time over starting from scratch. :(

TIA for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -llog

was commented out of Android.mk by previous programmer.

Still not too sure how the mk file works but it's working for now after uncommenting it.